# When reading an encrypted file I get "No matching key found for the ciphertext in the stream."

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cryptography

Here's the code I use to get an encrypted file, following the documentation of Android. I was getting an error of "file already exists", that's why I delete the file if I have to write on it:

```java
private static EncryptedFile getEncryptedFile(Context mCtx, String fileName, boolean write){
        File file = new File(mCtx.getFilesDir(),fileName);

        if(write && file.exists())
            file.delete();

        try {
            return new EncryptedFile.Builder(
                    mCtx,
                    file,
                    Objects.requireNonNull(getMasterKey(mCtx)),
                    EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
            ).build();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static MasterKey getMasterKey(Context mCtx) {
        try {
            KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    Constants.MASTER_KEY_ALIAS,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                    .setKeySize(KEY_SIZE)
                    .build();

            return new MasterKey.Builder(mCtx)
                    .setKeyGenParameterSpec(spec)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(mCtx.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error on getting master key", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And when trying to read from the file in the following way I get `java.io.IOException: No matching key found for the ciphertext in the stream.`.

```java
EncryptedFile encryptedFile = getEncryptedFile(mCtx, filename, false);

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = encryptedFile.openFileInput();

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =
                    new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String line = reader.readLine();
            if(line == null)
                return new ArrayList<T>();
            while(line != null){
                stringBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
```

The error usually at `reader.readLine()`. I can't tell why, I have the latest version of Crypto and everything. Any ideas?